How should I see this problem as? Normal or Time Series?
I have multiple independent simulated time series data (for physic experiment). Each time series has t = 0 to 10000, and 7 features with 1 target. I want to build a model that I can train on all the simulated data and make prediction on dataset Test which has only 7 features and the Time column (t=0 to 10000) without the Target. (Completely independent case of the training set)
I tried to think this as a time-series problem since target is time dependent but my goal here seems not? Because if I train a time series model, my Test set needs a historical part, but in my case,my data does not.

welcome to the community.
Let me imagine this problem to be a classification task depending upon the smartwatch accelerometer and gyroscope data collected over time (time series);
Say we have a target variable where we need to predict what activity the human is doing;
You can proceed to input these numeric data normally in your algorithm (either a DNN or some ML algorithm) and let the algorithm figure out what the target variable would be. Don't forget to standardize your features!
To proceed with these kinds of problems, I always suggest doing some EDA, i.e. checking how these 7 features vary depending on the target class. For example, on the smartphone data (accelerometer) for an idle person (sitting or lying)  is drastically different from a dynamic person (walking, running).
If you see these patterns already, you can expect your algorithm to perform reasonably well. Good luck :)
